# Извлечь строку из текста, начиная с заданного слова и до новой строки \n

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, текст

Задача заключается в извлечении строки начинающейся с определённого слова и   заканчивающейся знаком перевода строки (\n).

Пример:

```
data_list =["text\n text.....\nKeywords: key, key, key\n text......\n"]
```

Нужно извлечь строку:

```
'Keywords: key, key, key'
```

но при этом не известно где в тексте она находится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вытащите регулярным выражением, например:

```
text = "text\n text.....\nKeywords: key, key, key\n text......\n"

import re
match = re.search('(Keywords: .+?)\n', text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))  #  "Keywords: key, key, key"
```

Скобки указывают область, которую вы хотите вытащить. А сами строки внутри скобок можно получить через `group`. Если же по шаблону функции `search` ничего не будет найдено, вернется `None`, поэтому желательно прорять значение.

В регулярке мы указываем что нас интересует строка, начинающиеся на `Keywords:`  после нее идут любые символы до символа `\n`.

---

Дополню ответ из уточнения в комментария:

```
import re

data_list = ["text\n text.....\nKeywords: key, key, key\n key key key\n 1 text......\n"]
for text in data_list:
    match = re.search('(Keywords: .+)\n', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if match:
        #  b'Keywords: key, key, key\n key key key\n 1 text......'
        print(match.group(1).encode())
```

Результат вывел в качестве байтового массива, чтобы можно было видеть, что символы `\n` на месте.

Comment: Без `re.DOTALL` флага, можно [проще регулярное выражение использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597529/23044)

Comment: А если строка имеет вид:     data_list =["text\n text.....\nKeywords: key, key, key\n key key key\n 1  text......\n"] то есть строка с Keywords имеет более одного спец символа \n

Comment: @MaxIvanov, т.е. вам нужно до конца строки после Keywords собрать?

Comment: @MaxIvanov, обновил ответ

Comment: @MaxIvanov Если требуется извлечь всё содержимое в text, начиная с word и до самого конца, то код ещё проще: `result = text[text.find(word):]`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы извлечь всё, начиная со слова: `'Keywords'` и до конца строчки (до перевода строки):

```
import re

word = "Keywords"
result = re.search(re.escape(word) + '.*', text).group()
# -> 'Keywords: key, key, key'
```

Точка по умолчанию (без `re.DOTALL`) не совпадает с `\n`, поэтому можно использовать простое регулярное выражение, если только до первой новой строки (`'\n'`) текст извлечь. Иначе можно `flags=re.DOTALL`, чтобы до конца текста всё содержимое забрать.

`re.escape()` используется на случай, если word может содержать символы, которые являются специальными в регулярных выражениях (`*+.` итд).

Можно обойтись без регулярных выражений (менее удобно):

```
assert word in text and '\n' not in word
text += '\n' # make sure there is a newline

i = text.find(word)
result = text[i:text.find('\n', i)]
```

Тот же результат.

Если требуется извлечь всё содержимое в text, начиная с word и до самого конца:

```
assert word in text 
result = text[text.find(word):]
```

Comment: Полезно, мне нравится :)